# ActiveX vulnerability

Tags: security, delphi, activex

I am using Delphi and I want to use an ActiveX component (for compression) in my application. Will this make my program more vulnerable to virus attacks? My program is a backup application that uses FTP and sockets to transfer files and messages. My program has nothing to do with an Internet webbrowser.

Comment: Regardless of security, why don't you use one of the Open Source pure Delphi compression libraries available for Delphi? (such as [Abbrevia](https://github.com/TurboPack/Abbrevia)).

Comment: I have been trying all the possible Zipping tools in Delphi for the past few weeks. I have asked in all the possible forums too. I was using Zipmaster until now which is good but for a few setbacks. Abbrevia is comparatively far slower. I have check 7 Zip , Zipforge etc

Comment: I'm surprised that there's much performance difference for zipping. Mostly these libraries use zlib to do the work. And that's the same for all of them. Where I'd expect difference is if you use different compression algorithms. Are you comparing like with like?

Comment: Yes I am comparing like with like, Also testing with same data with pre-decided sets of data. Abbrevia's demo program itself is very slow, I can see a lot of juggling between temp files. Zipmaster has only Standard encryption else it is the fastest. 7Zip does not have the Deflate64 to work with Delphi only 7z again this is slow. Zipforge does not handle extended-length path names ....Now I have to use Chilkat ActiveX as it takes care of all my requirements. I am most unhappy to use an non-Delphi component but am left with no choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveX per se does not of itself introduce security vulnerabilities. The horror stories relating to ActiveX are actually Internet Explorer horror stories. In the bad old days before Microsoft got wise to the dangers of the open internet, Internet Explorer would happily download ActiveX components from the internet and execute the ActiveX component's code from inside the browser process. This was of course a gaping security hole. Simply trick a user to navigate to your malicious site and then execute arbitrary code on their machine.

But that's not what you describe. You are using a third party component of your choice to perform some task. This is a completely different scenario. Now, that's not to say that this component does not have any vulnerabilities of itself, but the fact that it is consumed using ActiveX is not pertinent to that. If it has vulnerabilities then it would not matter whether it was a VCL component, an ActiveX component, or indeed any other component type.

Don't focus on the component architecture. It's the implementation of the component that matters.